# Returning PowerShell query to dropdown with separate names and values

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm creating an ASP.Net web application, part of which populates a dropdown with the results from a PowerShell query.  That part I can do, but what I ideally want is the PS query to return two properties per object, with one displayed in the dropdown and the other as the value if.

Research revealed that I might be able to do this using a `DataTable`, but my effort below does not work.  Instead of getting the DisplayName values in the dropdown, I get two property names (DisplayName & SipAddress) plus 'Length', repeated for each returned result.  If I check the value of the various DisplayName and SipAddress items in the list, they contain the correct data but I want the values of DisplayName as the list with the values of SipAddress as the corresponding values.

```cs
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
dt.Columns.Add("SipAddress");

var shell = PowerShell.Create();
shell.Commands.AddScript("Get-CsCommonAreaPhone | Select-Object DisplayName, SipAddress -ExpandProperty DisplayName | Sort-Object DisplayName");
var results = shell.Invoke();

foreach (var psObject in results)
{
    foreach (PSPropertyInfo prop in psObject.Properties)
    {
        var Name = prop.Name;
        var sip = prop.Value;
        dt.Rows.Add(Name, sip);
    }
}

capdroplist.DataSource = dt;
capdroplist.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
capdroplist.DataValueField = "SipAddress";
capdroplist.DataBind();
```

Comment: I think you want :             dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName",typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Length",typeof(int));

Comment: `does not work` elaborate please.

Comment: @jdweng I only want DisplayName and SipAddress both of which are string, the Length is coming about because of my poor understanding of DataTables and the interaction with Powershell.  Do I have to declare the types?

Comment: @Reniuz sorry I'm not very clear, will edit for clarification

Comment: The issue isn't with the datatables.  Your code is find adding two values.  You do not need two for loops.  Eliminate : foreach (PSPropertyInfo prop in psObject.Properties).  It looks like each row of the results is a psObject which contains a Name property and a Value.  So you want dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {psObject.Properties[0].Value, psObject.Properties[1].Value});

Comment: You are missing the .Value : psObject.Members["SipAddress"].Value.  You are getting the class name ot the object because it is internally performing .ToString() of the class object.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for that. I used the following dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {psObject.Members["DisplayName"].Value,psObject.Members["SipAddress"].Value}); This gives me the names in the dropdown and the sipaddress as the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to @jdweng as this was his answer (with a little tinkering) but as it was in the comments I can't seem to mark it as such.  Working code below.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("DisplayName");
            dt.Columns.Add("SipAddress");

            var shell = PowerShell.Create();
            shell.Commands.AddScript("Get-CsCommonAreaPhone -filter {DisplayName -like '*vdiv*'} | Select-Object DisplayName, SipAddress | Sort-Object DisplayName");
            var results = shell.Invoke();

            foreach (var psObject in results)
            {

                dt.Rows.Add(new object[] {psObject.Members["DisplayName"].Value,psObject.Members["SipAddress"].Value});

            }

            capdroplist.DataSource = dt;
            capdroplist.DataTextField = "DisplayName";
            capdroplist.DataValueField = "SipAddress";
            capdroplist.DataBind();
```